# How to run maven tests with surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, junit, github-actions, maven-surefire-plugin

Im using gitactions, Im trying to run unit tests with maven whenever something is pushed up to a repository.
For this, im using a yml file that executes the command "mvn test".

But no tests run...
[Image of mvn test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iY6m.png)

I have a pom.xml file that looks like this.
In the build tag you can see how Ive configured surefire.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>oligtest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>
                        /oligtest/src/test/java/Check_If_Year_Is_Leap_Year.java
                    </additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
                
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>


<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

This is my yml file.

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Set up JDK 17
  uses: actions/setup-java@v3
  with:
    java-version: '17'
    distribution: 'temurin'
    cache: maven
- name: Build with Maven
  run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
- name: run tests
  run: mvn test
```

To fix the problem, Ive heard I can use surefire.
But I havent gotten it to work.
Ive heard I should refer to a path to the tests, but im unsure where to put this path.
I heard something about the tag "additionalClasspathElements" and put it there in pom.xml.
But that didnt work.

This is my project path. The tests in "Check_If_Year_Is_leap_Year" has the tests I want to run:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoBp5.png)

Does anyone knwo what Im doing wrong, and how to correct it?

Comment: First the class you would like to run as a test is in the default package which means directly in `src/test/java/..`..but you should define a package `src/test/java/<package>/ClassToTest.java`...furthermore your test class does not follow the naming convention for unit tests which should be `NameOfTheClassTest.java` ...furthermore you should use the most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin (3.0.0-M7) and do not configure a supplemental class path element if don't understand the intention etc.

Comment: Apart from that it is wrong as given... and do not `<version>RELEASE</version>` replace that with the correct version.. furthermore your pipeline defines two steps `Build with Maven` and `run tests` which makes no sense to separate those things because the life cycle `package` already contains the `test` life cycle (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Also check all the warnings you have during your build and clean them up...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The problem was my path specification.

I change the content of in the build tags inside the pom to this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>
                        /**/*Check_If_Year_Is_Leap_Year.java
                    </include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```